# What is the default size for the select element rendered by a h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

According to the JSF specification, a `h:selectOneMenu` is rendered as an HTML `<select>` element, with the "size" attribute set to the number of items:

> Use the number of items as the value of the "size" attribute.

(from the [tag documentation for selectOneMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/h/selectOneMenu.html))

However, when I use `h:selectOneMenu` in a page (using Mojarra or MyFaces), the size attribute of the rendered `<select>` is always set to 1.

Googling around also finds many pages which simply claim that `h:selectOneMenu` is suposed to render a "dropdown menu" (which is what most browsers render for `<select size="1">[...]`.

So is this a bug in the JSF spec, or is there some detail I overlooked? Why is the size not behaving as described in the spec?

Comment: I am facing this problem. With the size attribute, Bootstrap is not applying the correct style.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at [the source code of the MenuRenderer class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/MenuRenderer.java#MenuRenderer), from the **com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic** package, it's not clear whether it's a bug in the specification or not.

In order to render the h:selectOneMenu component, as well as the h:selectManyMenu component, the renderSelect method is called. About the size attribute :

- If it is not specified (which is the selectOneMenu case), a default value is set.
- If it is specified, `the "size" attribute will be rendered as one of the "pass thru" attributes`.

Here is the source code :

```java
 protected void  [More ...] renderSelect(FacesContext context,
                            UIComponent component) throws IOException {

    [...]

    // Determine how many option(s) we need to render, and update
    // the component's "size" attribute accordingly;  The "size"
    // attribute will be rendered as one of the "pass thru" attributes

    [...]

    // If "size" is *not* set explicitly, we have to default it correctly
    Integer size = (Integer) component.getAttributes().get("size");
    if (size == null || size == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        size = count;
    }
    writeDefaultSize(writer, size);

    RenderKitUtils.renderPassThruAttributes(context,
                                    writer,
                                    component,
                                    ATTRIBUTES,
                                    getNonOnChangeBehaviors(component));

    [...]

}
```

The confusion lies in the writeDefaultSize method. It always sets the default size to 1, even if the number of options to be rendered is given by an itemCount parameter :

```java
 protected void  [More ...] writeDefaultSize(ResponseWriter writer, int itemCount)
    throws IOException {
     // if size is not specified default to 1.
     writer.writeAttribute("size", "1", "size");
 }
```

So the size is neither behaving as described in the JSF spec, nor as described in the code's comments. It may not be a bug but it's a little confusing.